Go HMAC SHA256 Webhook Signature Validation Not Working as Expected
I've been trying to implement webhook signature validation in Go, similar to a working implementation I have in Node.js. However, the Go version of my code isn't producing the correct HMAC SHA256 signatures, and I can't figure out why. Below is the Node.js and Go code for comparison.
The Go code doesn't validate the webhook signature correctly, while the Node.js version works fine. Here are the differences I've noticed:
The Go code was incorrectly converting the secret to hex before using it in the HMAC function. This has been corrected.
What could still be causing the Go version to fail in producing the correct HMAC SHA256 signature? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
import crypto from "crypto";
import express from "express";

export const computeWebhookSignature = ({
    requestBody,
    secret,
    timestamp,
}: {
    requestBody: any;
    secret: string;
    timestamp: number;
}): string => {
    return crypto
        .createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(secret, "hex"))
        .update(Buffer.from(`${timestamp}.${JSON.stringify(requestBody)}`))
        .digest("hex");
};

const FIVE_MINUTES = 300000;
export const isValidWebhookRequest = ({
    requestBody,
    secret,
    timestamp,
    signature,
}: {
    requestBody: any;
    secret: string;
    timestamp: string;
    signature: string;
}): boolean => {
    const timestampD = new Date(Number.parseInt(timestamp));

    const timestampMs = timestampD.getTime();
    const now = Date.now();
    console.log(timestampMs, "timestamp");

    if (timestampMs > now || now - timestampMs > FIVE_MINUTES) {
        return false;
    }

    const computedSignature = computeWebhookSignature({ requestBody, secret, timestamp: timestampMs });
    if (computedSignature !== signature) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const WEBHOOK_SECRET = 'Zkoc9w7zM0twuBKGWtcDue3F1Ptj/VaOGwWmb/+gtT6IcGan2OXWsEzfEDjo+pTOj91mADx+8kfTbN4F2mrU8w==';
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const signature = req.headers['planetplay-signature'] as string;
    const timestamp = req.headers['planetplay-timestamp'] as string;

    console.log(signature);
    console.log(timestamp);
    console.log(body);

    const isValid = isValidWebhookRequest({
        requestBody: body,
        secret: WEBHOOK_SECRET,
        timestamp,
        signature
    });
    console.log(isValid);
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

const WEBHOOK_SECRET = "Zkoc9w7zM0twuBKGWtcDue3F1Ptj/VaOGwWmb/+gtT6IcGan2OXWsEzfEDjo+pTOj91mADx+8kfTbN4F2mrU8w=="

func computeWebhookSignature(requestBody string, secret string, timestamp int64) string {
    message := fmt.Sprintf("%d.%s", timestamp, requestBody)
    secertHex := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(secret))
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secertHex))
    h.Write([]byte(message))

    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func isValidWebhookRequest(requestBody string, secret, timestamp, signature string) bool {
    timestampInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(timestamp, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Invalid timestamp")

        return false
    }

    computedSignature := computeWebhookSignature(requestBody, secret, timestampInt)
    log.Printf("Computed signature: %s", computedSignature)
    log.Printf("Received signature: %s", signature)

    return computedSignature == signature
}

func webhookHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to read request body", http.StatusBadRequest)

        return
    }
    body := string(bodyBytes)

    signature := r.Header.Get("planetplay-signature")
    timestamp := r.Header.Get("planetplay-timestamp")

    if isValidWebhookRequest(body, WEBHOOK_SECRET, timestamp, signature) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Valid webhook request")
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid webhook request", http.StatusForbidden)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", webhookHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

Any help would be much appreciated.

In your Typescript code, you have this:
.createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(secret, "hex"))

This attempts to hex decode secret. Since secret starts with Z, NodeJS immediately stops processing it and creates an empty Buffer instance.
This behavior was really surprising to me and I thought I was doing something wrong while mucking around making a minimal reproduction. It turns out this is briefly touched upon in the documentation:

'hex': Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters. Data truncation may occur when decoding strings that do not exclusively consist of an even number of hexadecimal characters.

Meanwhile, in your Go code you have this:
    secertHex := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(secret))
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secertHex))

This produces a hex encoded representation of secret and uses it as the HMAC key. I'm guessing this is what you want to do.
So, try changing the Typescript code to this:
.createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(secret, 'utf8').toString('hex'))

